# Android: how to add scroll for surfaceview?

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I'm drawing some graphics and i would like to add scroll to it. But with the surface view how to add the scroll programatically ?

Answer (score 3):

SurfaceView is a very special component, it's not easy to mix it with other components. The main reason is due to how it works: when you use a SurfaceView, a new window will be created (by default behind the activity) and all the rendering in the SurfaceView will go to that window. SurfaceView will also "draw a hole" in the activity, so the window behind it will be visible.

SurfaceView needs to synchronize the window position with it's position, which is not done perfectly. For example if you put a SurfaceView inside something which can scroll, the window won't scroll (at least it didn't the last time I tried, around Froyo time).

Please provide some more information about what you are trying to do. If you just want to create a custom component, it's easier to just subclass View and override onDraw(Canvas).

Comment: @ Pal: Does this imply that I can't add a view for banner ad at the bottom of the screen, on top of surface view ?

Comment: @ Pal: thanks for the reply. i'm new to android. i'm developing simple application in which the user can select the colors & should be able to draw and finally it'll save as an image. But if i use canvas as u said i'm facing the following problem.... "first i'll draw some line by selecting green color. next if i select red color then whatever i've drawn previously(ex:in green color) that line also it is changing to red color like that".

So,i'm using the following example https://sites.google.com/site/tutorialsformobileprogramming/android-tutorials/android-files

Comment: @ Pal: but if i use the above example i'm not able to keep the scrolling, If i use canvas i can keep scrolling but i'm facing problem while changing the colors.
Can u pls let me know how to change the colors while drawing using canvas.

Comment: Unfortunately, without seeing your code I don't understand what is the problem.